# Is it possible to add a menu to a menu?

Tags: routes, navigation

I've created a "Staff menu" with various menu items. However I want to add it to the "Main menu" as a drop-down list (e.g. set Staff as Vertical, while Main is the navbar / horizontal menu).

Is it possible to just add a menu to a menu by creating a new menu item in the "Main menu" and linking it to "Staff menu" ?

Comment: Why dont you add it as a child menu items in the main menu itself?

Comment: Re-making/re-adding all the links takes time, so it would be easier to just add the menu to the other menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this module http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu then create parent menus and its child menus .Even you can create blocks inside with the sub menus.

Comment: Interesting, testing it now. Cheers!

Comment: This module does what I want, though I will have to style it to match what I had for the Superfish menu.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to add a menu to a menu as you describe.  However, you can make one big menu with parent/child/grandchild relationships and then use a module such as [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) or [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) to display it the way you want (main links horizontal/children drop-down vertically).

Comment: I'm using Superfish at the moment, but couldn't find/see an easy way to move the menus from Staff to the main menu.